# Symfony2 and FOS User Bundle - annotations

Tags: symfony, annotations, doctrine-orm, foreign-key-relationship, fosuserbundle

I've just started to learn the `symfony2` framework. Now I'm building my first bundle, a chat bundle. Everything works just fine but there is one thing I can't get a hang of, the foreign key to the user table. (I'm using the `FOS User Bundle` and Doctrine).

What should the annotation look like to the FOS User table (one to one)? And when fetching data from the chat table, will I get the user object aswell or do I need to fetch the user object after reading each row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved.**

Make sure to include the namespace of the user entity:

```
use Acme\UserBundle\Entity;
```

Add the annotation:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $user;
```